# There is some advantage in accessing a text file in binary mode?

Tags: python, file-io

We have a text file with several lines. The lines could end in CR+LF or LF. Each line have several fields separated by a field_separator (one or more characters).

**Sample 1:**

```
field_separator = '\n'
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(field_separator)
        for element in line:
            print(element)
```

**Sample 2:**

```
field_separator = b'\n'
with open('data.txt','br') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.endswith(b'\n'):
            line = line[0:-1]
        line = line.split(field_separator)
        for element in line:
            print(element)
```

**Question:** There is some adventage in access the text file in binary mode (sample 2 vs sample 1)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to preserve the line ending style, you *must* use binary mode. Text mode will always translate line endings to be consistent.

If you're using Python 3 and you don't know the character encoding mode of the file, you can use binary mode to read the file without triggering decode errors. Decoding the bytes into Unicode strings becomes your responsibility.